# route in .net 7 web api works when debugging but not in IIS

Tags: c#, api, .net-7.0

I just made a quick test of a .Net 7 Core Web Api and added a MovieController. when debugging in VS 2022 the route work. But if I add the project to IIS localy and try the same route I get a error 500.

**program.cs**

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Movie}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**MovieController**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Net7Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class MovieController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet("GetMovies")]
        public Movie Get(int id)
        {
            var movie = new Movie {Genre = new Genre("Sci fi"), Name = "Star Wars"};
            return  movie;
        }
    }
}
```

The route I try is /Movie/GetMovies?id=1

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have actual text of the error?

Comment: yes but it doesnt tell a lot......  
localhost can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot to install the .net core 7 iis hosting support so now it works after that. Link to the file https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-7.0.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer